# Having Trouble with a copy script in powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have written a simple powershell to copy files from one directory to another but I am having a syntax error I think.

```
$FileLocation = "C:\Quantifi\DailyBatch"
$FileLocation
$FilesToMove = Get-ChildItem -path $FileLocation | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-90) } | Select FullName
$FilesToMove
$CopyLocation = "U:\Archive"

ForEach ($FileToMove in $FilesToMove) { Copy-Item -Path $FileToMove -Destination $CopyLocation -Recurse }
```

I am getting the following error

***Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=C' does not exist.***

Any advice would be greatly apprecited

Comment: `Select FullName` -> `Select -ExpandProperty FullName`

Comment: `Select FullName` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`